# Regex for string starting with backslash & double quotes and ends with backslash & double quotes C#

Tags: c#, regex

Input: string input =  "\"string1 string2 \"";

Output: "string string2";

Check if string has \" and \" at beginning and end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you need: `^"\\"(.+)"\\"$`

Usage:

```
string str = @"\""some string\""";

var match = Regex.Match(str, @"^\\""(.+)\\""$");
if (match.Success)
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But Regex is giving a match for input: string str = "string2\""; I wanted to check for \" at both begining and end.

Comment: @Prince John Wesley : Thanks for the help. But Regex is giving a match for input: string str = "string2\"" ( Should return a false if the string doesnt contain "\"" both at the beginning and end).

Comment: @user1002386: are you sure? Mine doesn't give a success with `string str = @"some string\""";`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion IT WORKED. I made a mistake while outputting the modified string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression:

```
@"^"".*""$"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But Regex is giving a match for input: string str = "string2\"" ( Should return a false if the string doesnt contain "\"" both at the beginning and end).

Comment: @user1002386: did you test it?

Comment: Yes I tested it.. This is my code. static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = "string2\"";
            //string str = "\"string1 string2\"";
            Regex pattern = new Regex(@"^"".*""$");
            Match match = pattern.Match(str);
            if (match.Success)
            {
                str.Replace("\"", "");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(str);
            
            Console.ReadLine();
        }